# Testing smart contracts in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, unittesting

Testing smart contract Via another Testing Smart contract -

***X.sol***

```
contract X{
   function reservePlace(string _name) public payable returns (bool isNotReserved) {
      // use _name to reserve it 
   }
}
```

***TestX.sol***

```
contract TestX {

  X x = X(DeployedAddresses.X()); 

  function testReservePlace() public {
    // what to do here to call reservePlace with an address of my choice
    // right now it calls reservePlace with account that deployed the contract X 
    bool flag = x.reservePlace.value(1 ether)("hj");
  }
}
```

Now Truffle always uses the address that deployed contract X to fire this call.
In order to test X I need to be able to call the reservePlace with any random address. How can I do that?

I run the tests using `truffle test`

I can do the same in a JS test as -

```
x.reservePlace (arg1, {from: account2});
```